# Inspect SWT app at runtime?

Tags: java, swt, inspect

Is there any way to inspect (in a broad sense, to get any info) a SWT app without disassembling it (as it's packed as exe and I don't know how to extract it first)?

EDIT: turns out the app is a SWT one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[SwingExplorer](http://www.swingexplorer.com/) looks promising (and free)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, VisualVM gives a heap dump. That's already something.